# Disable Cron for specific interval of time

Tags: cron, services

I am developing a simple script that I run in case of excesive CPU ussage (detected via uptime) and **disables CRON** for some **minutes**:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
/etc/rc.d/cron stop
sleep 600 s
/etc/rc.d/cron start
```

Is this the **proper** way? I will have a stale script on my system for 600 seconds, not a great problem, I would say.
 Maybe CRON includes some feature for **scheduled restarting**? Or maybe any **service** can do this?
Something like:

```
/etc/rc.d/cron suspend -t 600s
```

Comment: Please note that `cron` is supposed to be running all the time. If any task was scheduled to run during those 600 seconds it will be lost with no trace.

Comment: What is cron calling/doing that is causing too much system load, that stopping new cron jobs from executing for 10 minutes will solve it?

Comment: You might be better off doing something like `pkill -STOP crond` to suspend the task, then use `-CONT` to make it continue. You should check if cron manages to run the jobs it should have once it wakes.  Otherwise move your cron jobs to `anacron`.

Comment: @ivanivan : CRON runs multiple scripts that I am developing and testing. If someone of them is buggy, it could take too much CPU time, so the system will get overloaded. It happened to me once, and, after a few hours, the operating system arrived to a denyal of service. Checking uptime each 5 minutes and stopping CRON for 10 minutes will allow me to detect the problem on time.

Comment: @SopalajodeArrierez, then would not it be easier to write a separate config file for a second `cron` instance that you'll start solely for debugging your scripts purposes and not mess with a system?

Comment: @Serge : the system itself is dedicated to the job that my scripts do. Another solution, by the way, could be to stop only the Cron Tab for the user that I use to program those scripts. And another solution would be to comment `#` (i.e: via `sed`) the CronTab. Another one would be to rename the Cron Tab for that user... etc. There are lots of solutions for lots of problems, but the original question here explain a minimal case in order to obtain an answer just to the "Disable Cron for specific interval of time" matter.